# How do I change the animation style of a jQuery Accordion?

Tags: jquery, animation, coding-style, accordion, slide

Is there a way to change the default animation that jQuery accordion uses?  It appears to be "slide" but I'd like to use a Bounce or Drop effect.

Here's my current code:

```
$("#accordion").accordion({
    autoHeight: false,
    collapsible: true,
    event: 'click',
    active: 4
});
```

I'd like to change this from a slide to a drop or a bounce.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`animated` option for this](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion#option-animated), for example to get your bounce:

```
$("#accordion").accordion({ 
  animated: 'bounceslide',
  autoHeight: false, 
  collapsible: true, 
  event: 'click', 
  active: 4
});
```

The default is `'slide'`, [you can view a demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/B4T2K/).

Comment: Note: as of jQuery UI 1.9 change `animated` to `animate`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **[JQuery UI effects](http://jqueryui.com/demos/)** if you want more animations styles. And yes there are bounce and drop effects there too.

**Note:** You can also construct your own animations styles using **[`animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)** method.

Comment: Yes, but how do I actually apply those UI animation effects to the accordion code?  Where does it go and how does it need to be written?